# Route between two private networks

Tags: virtualbox, routing, freebsd, gateway

I have a two private networks (`home`: 192.168.1.0/24 and `virtual`: 10.10.0.0/24) which I like to connect and have them to be reachable in both ways.

Network `home` is managed by my home router which is also my default gateway (192.168.1.1). My workstation is Windows 10 (192.168.1.4, static DHCP). On this machine, I have set up two servers with VirtualBox running FreeBSD 10.3:

bsd1dc:

em0: bridged network, static DHCP, 192.168.1.20, gateway 192.168.1.1

em1: internal network, manual IP, 10.10.0.1, mask 255.255.255.0

bsd1srv:

em0: internal network, manual IP, 10.10.0.5, mask 255.255.255.0, gateway 10.10.0.1

The internal network runs flawlessly as there is a Samba-internal DNS server. Provisioned domain with all servers joined to that domain. More machines will be added later.

For outbound access in the internal network, I have configured bsd1dc with `net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`, `gateway_enable="YES"`, `pf_enable="YES"`, and `/etc/pf.conf`: `nat pass on em0 from em1:network to any -> em0`.

All hosts in `home`are reachable from `virtual`as well as all hosts on the Internet.

What routing do I need to configure now to access 10.10.0.0/24 from my Windows 10 machine without SSH tunnneling via 192.168.1.20? Is that possible at all because these are private networks?

I also have modified my Windows routing table:

```
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
  8...0a 00 27 00 00 08 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  4...d0 50 99 93 d7 0e ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  7...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  3...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.4     20
        10.10.0.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.1.20      192.168.1.4     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung       192.168.1.4    276
      192.168.1.4  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       192.168.1.4    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       192.168.1.4    276
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.56.1    266
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung       192.168.1.4    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       192.168.1.4    276
===========================================================================
```

but no avail:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 10.10.0.1

Ping wird ausgeführt für 10.10.0.1 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.

Ping-Statistik für 10.10.0.1:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 3, Empfangen = 0, Verloren = 3
    (100% Verlust),
STRG-C
^C
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.1.20

Ping wird ausgeführt für 192.168.1.20 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 192.168.1.20: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.1.20: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.1.20: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64
Antwort von 192.168.1.20: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=64

Ping-Statistik für 192.168.1.20:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Mittelwert = 0ms
```

A traceroute for both:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 192.168.1.20

Routenverfolgung zu 192.168.1.20 über maximal 30 Hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.20

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.

C:\Windows\system32>tracert 10.10.0.1

Routenverfolgung zu 10.10.0.1 über maximal 30 Hops

  1     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  2     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  3     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  4
```

Solution for the issue based on Nathan Shiraini's ideas:

After adding the static route to my machine, it still didn't work. Pointing to `pf` was the right thing to do. `em0` on `bsd1dc` was previously configured with VirtualBox as NAT and `pf` was acting like a NAT router. After turning into a bridged network, `pf` blocked all inbound traffic by retaining the NAT router. Disabing `pf` was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CMD command to add an IP route. Example adapted to your case:

```
ROUTE ADD 10.10.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.20 METRIC 5
          ^-net to reach  ^-subnet mask  ^-gateway to use  ^-keep that number low
```

You can use the parameter `-p` after `ROUTE` to keep that route across reboots (i.e. `ROUTE -P`). And remember to run that command in an elevated command prompt.

***EDIT*: Actually the solution has nothing to do with routes on the Windows machine, see comments and main post**

Comment: That was my first idea, see my edit, but the ping does no work.

Comment: More interesting than a ping, I would like to see what happens when you run `tracert` to an IP of the virtual network as it may indicate if the routing is done correctly.

Comment: Another edit made. I have the feeling that some config has to be done with `pf` on `bsd1dc`.

Comment: Perhaps add another line to pf.conf where you replace `em0`with `em1` and vice versa?

Comment: You just made the point, it was `pf` which blocked the traffic. I will update my question with the solution based on your ideas. Since you gave me the right pointers, I will accept your answer.